# Call to a member function getValue() on null

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, magento2.2.7, product-weight

Magento 2.2.7

Getting this error in the error_log and customer get's white screen when trying to login to site,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in 
/home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/Product/Type.php:338 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(1926): Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type->getWeight(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) 
#1 /home/website/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Interceptor.php(1259): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->getWeight() 
#2 /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item.php(433): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor->getWeight() 
#3 /home/website/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/Interceptor.php(128): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item->setProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)) 
#4 /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ResourceModel/Quote/Item/Collection.php(275): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Interceptor->setProduct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Mode in /home/website/public_html/vendor/magento/module-bundle/Model/Product/Type.php on line 338
```

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure where this is coming from, all of the products have a weight set.

Comment: do you have custom module that extends the module-bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an old migrated row in the quote table from the M1 to M2 migration. Deleting that row removed the error for the specific customer account.

Comment: how did you get to know which row is older in the quote table?

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is near 5 years old, but I found it today while looking for an explanation of this issue I was having and I figured out the proper solution on my case.

My custom grid uses a collection that have a joined field, and that field can be NULL when the main table does not have defined the entity id of the joined table, so for those cases I was getting same error like yours while I try to export. My solution was simply to make the column Alias with an IF condition that checks if it was NULL and then for those cases I add the column with an empty string, then export run correctly and nothing was affected on the grid:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function _initSelect()
{
    parent::_initSelect();
    $this->joinCustomerTable();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return $this
 */
private function joinCustomerTable()
{
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $customerIdField = $connection->quoteIdentifier('main_table.customer_id');

    $this->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            ['customer' => $this->getTable('customer_entity')],
            "customer.entity_id={$customerIdField}",
            [
                'customer_email' => 'IF(`customer`.`email` IS NOT NULL, `customer`.`email`, "")'
            ]
        );
    return $this;
}
```